# Will there still be aliasing after I run my copy methods?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have a map with a map as values and a map with a set as values (in java).  I wrote a method for each to copy them, and try to avoid aliasing, but by the way my program is behaving, I'm not sure they work.

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> deepCopySet(Map<String, Set<String>> ruledOutCount) {
    Map<String,Set<String>> copy = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : ruledOutCount.entrySet())
    {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), new HashSet<String>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return copy;
}

private Map<SG, Map<classObj, Integer>> deepCopyMap(Map<SG, Map<classObj, Integer>> classCountPerSG) 
{
    Map<SG,Map<classObj,Integer>> copy = new HashMap<SG,Map<classObj,Integer>>();
    for(Map.Entry<SG, Map<classObj,Integer>> entry : classCountPerSG.entrySet())
    {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), new HashMap<classObj,Integer>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

classObj and SG are my own objects.
Is there any aliasing possible after I run these copy methods?
Thanks.

Comment: "but by the way my program is behaving, I'm not sure they work." What do you expect it to do, what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

The `deepCopySet` method looks fine.

The `deepCopyMap` method is also fine, but it depends on the types of `SG` and `classObj`: If it is possible that they are also maps (or other complex objects), you might get a shallow copy.

Be aware that Java does type checks only at compile time! So in the following code

```
StringBuilder willNotBeCopied = new StringBuilder();
Map evil = new HashMap();
evil.put("a", new HashSet(Arrays.asList(willNotBeCopied)));
Map shallowCopy = deepCopySet(evil);
willNotBeCopied.append("some text");
```

the `shallowCopy` map would contain *the same* StringBuilder instance (shallow copy).

Comment: Thanks!  Both of those objects just store strings and integers, so it should be fine